# Disable all breakpoints without current breakpoint in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

I used Intellij IDEA CE version 2016.3.4 and I have simple question about breakpoints.

Is it possible to disable all breakpoints except one (current one) and without editing all other? Maybe there is any "one click" option ?

Example:

```
+ means Enabled breakpoint
- means Disabled breakpoint

(Before)
[+] Breakpoint1
[+] Breakpoint2 - current
[+] Breakpoint3
[+] Breakpoint4 

(After mute/disable all without current)
[-] Breakpoint1
[+] Breakpoint2 - current
[-] Breakpoint3
[-] Breakpoint4
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The shortest solution i can think of is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> ( <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> for mac ) to open All breakpoints window. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ( <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ) to select all of them and <kbd>Space</kbd> to disable all. After that you can enable your current breakpoint.

Comment: I am satisfied with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In menu, `Help->Find Action` and type breakpoint and select view breakpoints.

Then `Ctrl+A ( Cmd+A )` to select all of them and `Space` to disable all

Then you can enable new breakpoint at the location required.